# generate Fake data and " AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet" error

Tags: python, django

I want to generate fake data for my app in Admin panel,but I get below error .
When I use `python manage.py runserver` the app execute but without fake data.
I want to generate fake data by stand alone file (population.py) , but I get Error .

There are some solution according this error in stackoverflow I check all post but don't solve my problem .

**This is my error message **

```
  File "population.py", line 14, in <module>
    from first_app.models import Topic, Webpage, AcsessRecord
  File "E:\Dropbox\CS\Project\Project\django\django_BC\django_pro\first_app\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Topic(models.Model):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dj1.11\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dj1.11\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dj1.11\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

**population.py** file for generate fake data

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_pro.settings')

import django


# setup django according above setting
django.setup

from faker import Faker
import random
from first_app.models import Topic, Webpage, AcsessRecord



# import fake module

# create an objet from faker
fakegen = Faker()

# The main info is topic before import class of model that we crated
# becuse we want to fill database similary model

# We want to add random for topic from a list

topics = ['search', 'social', 'marjetplace', 'news', 'games']

# Randomally define topic


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t


def population(N=5):

    for entry in range(N):
        # Generate topic for entry
        top = add_topic

        name_fake = fakegen.name()
        url_fake = fakegen.URL()
        date_fake = fakegen.date()

        web_page = Webpage.object.get_or_create(
            topics=top, url=url_fake, name=name_fake)[0]

        acc_rec = AcsessRecord.object.get_or_create(
            name=web_page, date=date_fake)[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("start for genarate please wait...")
    population(20)
    print("the population is complete ")
```

**models.py** this is code for model class

```
    from django.db import models


class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name


class Webpage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AcsessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing brackets

```
django.setup --> django.setup()
```